# Error in Java JFrame code

Tags: java, swing

Getting error during declaration of class Object.

Error Occurring during object declaration in main class.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import  javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class basic extends JFrame  {
public void BasicGUI()
{
    setTitle("Hello");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setSize(500,200);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton btn1= new JButton("Hello");
    btn1.setVisible(true);
    JButton btn2=new JButton("world");
    btn2.setVisible(true);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   BasicGUI b= new BasicGUI();
}

}
```

Comment: Your constructor cant be declared as a "void". Your constructor is different than the class name "BasicGUI" vs "basic". Buttons are visible by default.

Comment: `BasicGUI b= new BasicGUI();` should be `basic b = basic();` bit more accurately, `public class basic extends JFrame  {` should be `public class BasicUI extends JFrame  {` and `public void BasicGUI()` should be `public BasicGUI()`

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an error because you're trying to instantiate an object BaiscGUI which dosen't exist (BasicGUI it's a method not a class), you should instantiate with the class basic b = new basic(), and then call the BasicGUI like this b.BasicGUI();

Answer (score 0):

The **constructor** (in the following example `public BasicGUI()`) is automatically called when you instantiate a class, and it has to have the same name as the class.

```
import  javax.swing.JFrame;  
import javax.swing.JButton; 

public class BasicGUI extends JFrame {

public BasicGUI()
{
    setTitle("Hello");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setSize(500,200);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton btn1= new JButton("Hello");
    btn1.setVisible(true);
    JButton btn2=new JButton("world");
    btn2.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   BasicGUI b = new BasicGUI();
}
}
```

What you are trying to do in your code snippet, is to instantiate a method, which is not possible (and makes no sense).

I guess the code I proposed is what you were trying to do